# ConnectedRouter TypeError: Cannot read property 'dispatch' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

trying my hands on React/Redux following the tutorial on Part 3: https://tighten.co/blog/react-101-routing-and-auth.

Part 1 and 2 has been awesome until part 3 where I bumped into the error in the title. I'm pretty sure I've been following the tutorial fine up to this point.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance SO.

[image: Error Info]

```
The above error occurred in the <ConnectedRouter> component:
index.js:1446
    in ConnectedRouter (at App.js:39)
    in App (created by Context.Consumer)
    in Connect(App) (at src/index.js:11)
    in Provider (at src/index.js:10)
```

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './containers/App';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { configureStore } from './store/configureStore';

const store = configureStore();

    ReactDOM.render(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
      </Provider>,
      document.getElementById('app')
    )
```

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { ConnectedRouter } from 'react-router-redux';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'
import { history } from './../store/configureStore';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import Header from '../containers/Header';
import Home from '../containers/Home';
import Signup from '../containers/Signup';
import Login from '../containers/Login';
import Favorites from '../containers/Favorites';

const PrivateRoute = ({component: Component, authenticated, ...props}) => {
    return (
        <Route
            {...props}
            render={(props) => authenticated === true
                ? <Component {...props} />
                : <Redirect to={{pathname: '/login', state: {from: props.location}}} />}
        />
    );
};

const PublicRoute = ({component: Component, authenticated, ...props}) => {
    return (
        <Route
            {...props}
            render={(props) => authenticated === false
                ? <Component {...props} />
                : <Redirect to='/favorites' />}
        />
    );
};


class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
                <div>
                    <Header />

                    <div className="container">
                        <Route exact path="/" component={ Home }/>
                        <PublicRoute authenticated={this.props.authenticated }  path="/signup" component={ Signup } />
                        <PublicRoute authenticated={this.props.authenticated }  path="/login" component={ Login } />
                        <PrivateRoute authenticated={this.props.authenticated }  path="/favorites" component={ Favorites } />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ConnectedRouter>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return { authenticated: state.auth.authenticated };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
```

**ConfigureStore.js**

```
import { createStore, compose, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import ReduxPromise from 'redux-promise';
import rootReducer from '../reducers';
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';
import { routerMiddleware } from 'react-router-redux';

export const history = createHistory();

export function configureStore(initialState) {
  const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    initialState,
    compose (
      applyMiddleware(ReduxPromise, routerMiddleware(history)),
      window.devToolsExtension ? window.devToolsExtension() : f => f
    )
    //window.devToolsExtension ? window.devToolsExtension() : undefined
  );

  if (module.hot) {
    // Enable Webpack hot module replacement for reducers
    module.hot.accept('../reducers', () => {
      const nextRootReducer = require('../reducers').default;
      store.replaceReducer(nextRootReducer);
    });
  }

  return store;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a Provider element at the parent level of ConnectedRouter

Comment: It's there in index.js. Is it misplaced?

Comment: It looks like `store` in react router is undefined. Are you sure you are returning the configured store in `configureStore()`? If yes, it might help if you post the code inside that file as well (it's likely where the problem is happening).

Comment: @emroussel, right. I've edited the post to include configureStore()

Comment: Solved it. Reverted to an older but compatible npm package of react-redux, react-router-dom/redux, redux and redux-promise at the time the project was published. It fixed the issue for now. Not sure what has changed. Will look into it again.

Comment: I am facing the same issue after upgrading react and react-redux packages in an old template. Not sure where to start looking into.

Comment: @Ashutosh, can't rollback to previous packages? Let me know if you need to reference my package for the version numbers. Upgrading isn't my priority now so I'll just stick to using what I have for the time being. Sorry.

Comment: @f0rfun Thanks, I have reverted the upgrades but will need to look into the actual issue.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The package [react-router-redux is deprecated](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux#project-deprecated).

Use [connected-react-router](https://github.com/supasate/connected-react-router) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. Reverted to an older but compatible npm package of react-redux, react-router-dom/redux, redux and redux-promise at the time the project was published. Non-issue for now. Not sure what has changed. Will look into it again.

Comment: This is marked correct, but [react-router-redux is deprecated](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux#project-deprecated) and the docs suggest using [connected-react-router](https://github.com/supasate/connected-react-router).

Comment: Upgrading to connected-react-router doesn't eliminate the error, so I'd say that this answer is in fact more correct.